# TCP connecting to server is slow?

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock2

I am running a TCP Server which accepts java clients fast. But the c++ Client does need like ~1Second to connect to it. (used a scopetime logger) What i do is, i connect to the server befor sending and the communication is done i do close the socket and the next time i do send something i do the same procedure.

the for loop to connect to the socket really really slow. How do i improve this?! (the connect is slow)

is it the Client or meight it be the server here? If it could be the server i wonder why it isnt slow if a java client connects

```
bool JIMDBClient::connect()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    m_sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo* result = nullptr, *ptr = nullptr, hints;

    int iResult;

    /* Initialisiere TCP für Windows ("winsock"). */
    WORD wVersionRequested;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        m_connected = false;
        return false;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(m_host.c_str(), m_port.c_str(), &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        m_connected = false;
        return false;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != nullptr; ptr = ptr->ai_next) // this is slow
    {
        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        m_sock = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
                        ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (m_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            m_connected = false;
            return false;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = ::connect(m_sock, ptr->ai_addr, static_cast<int>(ptr->ai_addrlen));
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(m_sock);
            m_sock = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (m_sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        m_connected = false;
        return false;
    }

    if(!handShake()) //only takes around 450µS !
    {
        LOG_WARN << "handshake failed";
        WSACleanup();
        m_connected = false;
        return false;
    }

    m_connected = true;
    return m_connected;
}
```

Comment: Does it connect on the first protocol you get back in `result`? Or does it try several? Which protocols work and don't work?

Comment: it does connect to the second which is "6" if i print it. which would fitt to the server side `hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;`

Comment: So is the delay in the call that fails, or the call that succeeds? (I would guess the former.) And what are the parameters in the the call that fails? Perhaps you could filter or order the results to make it more likely that you succeed on the first try. Or even attempt multiple connections in parallel.

Comment: Is your server using IPv4 or 6 or both?

Comment: you can use async-io to speed things up

Comment: It always fails at: ai_prot:6ai_fam:23ai_socktyp:1 If i "filter" that it works insane fast. I need to check on which settings the server Starts, second

Comment: The server starts on fam:2 type 1 proto 6. Well can you tell me if i can simply set this in the client or does that make troubles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that your server only supports IPv4 or IPv6 you can say that in the hints that you pass to `getaddrinfo`:

```
hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // Or AF_INET6
```

Comment: AF_INET6 is 23, AF_INET is 2 - so the latter seems to be the one you want.

Comment: Right serverside is AF_INET and i said unspec at Client which causes in a long search. Every "version" he checks takes 1 second.

Comment: A better solution might be to make your server support both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: How do i do this? Can i set this in hints somehow or do i need to listen on 2 sockets?

Comment: That sounds like a different question - I don't know what your server code looks like. And I'm afraid I don't actually know the answer.

Comment: Okay no problem, you did solve my issue thats all i needed at this point. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes is not the application, but the network path: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8305.html#section-7